# How to trace C# project on Linux via VSCode (Cannot build, I just want to trace)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have a project that is developed with C# and it can be run on my Windows PC.

But I want to port some part to a embedded system, so I moved on to a Linux PC and starting my porting job.

But unfortunately I cannot use any code trace features (such as find the reference, find the implement, etc..) on VS Code (on Linux).

It seems the OmniSharp extension cannot parser my project file (`.csproj`).

I don't need to build it, just want to trace code. Is there any other way to arrive this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of .Net does the project use?

Comment: @phuzi I found <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion> on my project file, should be 4.5? But I don't need to build it, I just want to trace code (code navigation) to find the references (caller?) to help my porting job.

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5 is not compatible with Linux/MacOS, only Windows. You will likely need to install some version of Mono on your system. I believe OmniSharp is only compatible with .Net Core onwards (.Net Core 1.0 - .Net Core 3.2 and then .Net 5 and 6)